# Is there an option to confirm file moving on a remote host in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, warnings, settings

I use PhpStorm at work daily and our company edits files stored remotely using SFTP... When browsing for files in the Remote Host viewer, I keep accidentally "dragging and dropping" different files and folders into random locations without noticing! It then becomes a search for where these files ended up (huge waste of time)

Does PhpStorm have a setting to warn you before moving files on a remote host? If so where is it located?

I've searched the web and can't find anything, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does PhpStorm have a setting to warn you before moving files on a remote host?

AFAIK - not really.

But you can use the following option to be more clear with your intentions (to prevent such accidental moves):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`
3. Enable `Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only` option

[image]